# Linux hybrid graphics - how to switch

Tags: linux, graphics, nvidia

I'm trying to use the nouveau driver, but my Intel card is always used.
Here's the output of `xrandr --listproviders` :

`Provider 0: id: 0x6b cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 8 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x4, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:nouveau`

But when I try to switch through DRI_PRIME, nothing change :
`DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`, result is :

`OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile`

`DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`, result is:

`OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile`

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed those PPAs :
https://launchpad.net/~commendsarnex/+archive/ubuntu/winedri3
https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers